# OpenGL vertices being rendered clipped

Tags: c++, opengl

I haven't done much OpenGL stuff, I assume there is an obvious cause of what I am seeing.

Basically the pictures below explain everything.

The only thing changed between the images is the x rotation on the projection matrix.

OpenGL 1.1 on Windows.

Any help is much appreciated.

[image: Good]

[image: BAd]

Comment: There's more clipping happening than you suspect. See how the grey box at the bottom has a flat top? I'd bet that's clipped too.

Comment: yea I noticed that too

Comment: Check your near/far planes. It's likely your model is exceeding them.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, that appeared to work at first, but it actually hasn't fixed it. I was not on the correct angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a ortho projection. I suggest you increase the range between the near and far value. Unlike perspective projection, where due to nonlinearity you should limit the near-to-far range to what's absolutely necessary, you can safely choose a near/far range for ortho that's very wide without running into trouble. I suggest you use [-1000, 1000] (with a 24 bit depth buffer that gives you a depth resolution of ~1/8000 viewspace Z units).